# Variable Explorer in Spyder doesn't show variables values

Tags: python, spyder

I am using Python 3.8 Spyder and I wanted to see the values of my variables in variable explorer after I ran the program, but when I doubled click on the variables name here
[image: ..]

I saw this screen:
[image: ..]

How can I change back the settings in order to be able to see all the values of my variables?

Comment: You need to install Numpy on the same environment as you installed Spyder to visualize Numpy arrays through its Variable explorer.

Comment: Thanks! I installed again numpy on this environment and now it works.